# How do I show values in columns once rather than repeating in SQL?

Tags: sql, join, select

DISCLAIMER: New at SQL and learning on the fly...

I'm trying to combine multiple tables in SQL; however, when I run the below SQL code I get the same result listed multiple times. Is there any way to have the below customer show once rather than repeating? I've tried doing a `GROUP BY` function, but that doesn't appear to work.

```
SELECT
    C.CustomerID,
    C.Name
FROM 
    finance.dim.customer C
JOIN 
    finance.dbo.fIntacct FI ON C.CustomerID = FI.CustomerID
JOIN 
    finance.dbo.ItemMapping IM ON FI.ItemId = IM.ItemID
JOIN 
    BillingAndPayments.dbo.agg_Batch A ON FI.CustomerID = A.CustomerUserName
WHERE 
    C.CustomerID = 'TESTCOMPANY'
```

The result I get is

```
Customer ID | Name
------------+-------------
TESTCOMPANY | Test Company
TESTCOMPANY | Test Company
TESTCOMPANY | Test Company
```

Comment: Sample data and the expected output would be very useful here.

Comment: You probably want `SELECT DISTINCT` instead of `SELECT`?

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to use the `distinct` modifier:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT -- Here
    C.CustomerID,
    C.Name
FROM finance.dim.customer C
    JOIN finance.dbo.fIntacct FI
    ON C.CustomerID = FI.CustomerID
    JOIN finance.dbo.ItemMapping IM
    ON FI.ItemId = IM.ItemID
    JOIN BillingAndPayments.dbo.agg_Batch A
    ON FI.CustomerID = A.CustomerUserName
WHERE C.CustomerID = 'TESTCOMPANY'
```

Comment: If I was to add a column summing numbers, such as the total of all envelopes sent by CustomerID, how would that look with the SELECT DISTINCT feature?

Comment: @KamilOrszulak . . . You would use `GROUP BY` instead.  It is just a small change to the query.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I've added `SUM(A.TotalEnvelopes)` after `C.Name` and then the last line of code is `GROUP BY C.CustomerID`, but receive and error message stating: Column 'finance.dim.customer.Name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @KamilOrszulak . . . Put both columns in the `GROUP BY`.